# Problem with lists and "allowed_block_types" in functions.php (since WP 6.1.1)

Tags: functions, block-editor, lists

I often use the *"allowed_block_types_all"* function in my **functions.php** to disable unnecessary blocks.

**Since WP version 6.1.1** (or 6.1) there is a problem that the list block in Gutenberg doesn't work properly anymore when I use this function. Lists can then be created in Gutenberg, but they can no longer be expanded with the Enter key.

Can anyone reproduce this problem as well?

This is my code:

```
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types_all', 'custom_allowed_block_types' );
function custom_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks ) {
    return array(
        'core/paragraph',
        'core/heading',
        'core/list',
        'core/image',
        'core/gallery',
        'core/file',
        'core/audio',
        'core/video',
        'core/table',
        'core/html',
        'core/columns',
        'core/media-text',
        'core/spacer',
        'core/shortcode',
        'core/separator',
        'core/embed',
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WordPress 6.1 list items are now their own blocks, so you will need to add `core/list-item` to the list of allowed blocks.

Comment: Oh man that's it. Thank's so much.

Comment: This works... Nice find!